# Timezone offset by timezone name for a specific date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, internationalization

How can I find timezone offset in hours or minutes using timezone name for a specific date.

Example use would be :

```
var offset = findOffset("America/New_York", new Date(2019,08,07))
// offset is -4
```

I am hoping to find a solution using native JS, but if it does not exist I am also ok with using some libraries.

Comment: You can [download the IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones)

Comment: If you don't mind using a third-party library, you can use date-fns and check out its [time zone features](https://date-fns.org/v2.1.0/docs/Time-Zones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the answer I found

```
const findTimeZoneOffset = (tz,date) => {
  let utcDate = new Date(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: "UTC" }));
  let tzDate = new Date(date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: tz }));
  let diff = ( tzDate.getTime() - utcDate.getTime() ) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
  return diff;
};
```

and as expected

```
findTimeZoneOffset("America/New_York", new Date(2019,08,07))
// returns -4
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) which is a JS library and it is quite popular (3,660,521 weeks NPM downloads). Moment and Moment Timezone are sibling libraries (Same developer).

The [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) library gives you offset in the output like shown below:

```
moment.tz("2013-12-01", "America/Los_Angeles").format(); // 2013-12-01T00:00:00-08:00

moment.tz("2013-06-01", "America/Los_Angeles").format(); // 2013-06-01T00:00:00-07:00
```

Comment: I am not trying to guess it, I already have that in my database for each user. I just want to get the offset for a given date using the timezone name

Comment: You can find the time at your timezone on the given date and then subtract it from the UTC time to calculate the offset. This should also work with the daylight savings time. Please let me know if it helps.